# Route internal requestes from Microservices in private subnet in AWS

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, microservices, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a couple of micro-services deployed using ECS in a private and public  subnets. These microservices are choreographed so they request each other with REST and need to know each other's IP locations. Currently I am not having any domain with route 53 to subdomain use it, so whenever I stop and start the services I have to update the tasks with new IPs every time and connect the services. Any ideas on how I can create a routing table or something similar where my ENV params remain same but request to those IPs from ENV params are redirected to correct IPs. I don't mind updating the routing table every time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[AWS CloudMap](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/) integrates with ECS to provide custom internal DNS names for your services, that resolve to the current internal IP address of the services.

Alternatively, you could look into [AWS AppMesh](https://aws.amazon.com/app-mesh) to create a service mesh. This is a bit more advanced than CloudMap, but also more flexible.